# string length not decremented when unset string index

Tags: php

I was trying to create palindrome by deleting one character from string at a time . While unsetting the string index .The string length is not getting reduced.

```
$s = "arun";
var_dump ($s);
$s[1] = NULL;
var_dump($s) ;
```

## output

```
string(4) "arun"
string(4) "aun"
```

Why does the length not reduced.

Comment: because the string did not decrement, but now contains a NULL character at that position

Comment: @FranzGleichmann but in all other cases NULL unset memory

Comment: yeah. the content. but not the *pointer*

Comment: NULL is a pointer to 0x00000000 address

Comment: I do not get the same result as OP : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e1880b6a1dd81198ed13a04310f55d0aca5edc8

Comment: @Zeratops i'd bet that's a matter of server encoding and stuff.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann My bad, turns out I should select "Raw" instead of "Text box" to see the actual output that OP is getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because you are not in any way reducing your string, but just replacing one character.

your string gets transformed from `a r u n` to `a (null) u n`, which is still four chars long.

to achieve your goal, use [substr_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php)

```
<?php
$s = "arun";
var_dump ($s); //arun
$s = substr_replace($s, "", 1,1);
var_dump($s); //aun
```

Answer (score 1):

You not really deleting anything, you are just setting `$s[1]` to null.
so what if its null? `$s[1]` is still part of string.

To fix this, `use substr()`

**Edit:**

Example:

```
$s = "arun";

var_dump ($s);
$s[1] = NULL;
$s = $s[0].substr($s,2); // get the first index and "un" then concatenate them
var_dump($s) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This array is still 4 elements, but in `$s[1]` is just `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because letters in output goes as follows: `aNULLun`

Split string to letters, unset specific index, join together again:

```
$s = "arun";
$s = str_split($s);
unset($s[1]);

var_dump(implode('', $s));
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d60ed2651a477c11684d774462c561def9572641)

Comment: while converting the complete string into an array, manipulating it and imploding it into a string again works, i'd think that using native string functions to solve the problem would be cleaner and provide much better performance, especially with large strings.